# How to get full year view in UICollectionviewCell with month block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i want to get full year `calendar` value in `UICollectionViewCell` with `month` block, and arranging with proper `day`, thanks in advance help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what you've tried? what error you are getting?? please don't ask if you haven't tried anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try this url...

https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout

apply this, hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar` with `UICollectionView` is good idea.

Here you get sample of `calendar` with `UICollectionView`. but you need some modification as per your requirement.

[CalendarIOS7](https://github.com/leverdeterre/CalendarIOS7)

Hope this help you.